# Address of property expression requested

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

i am passing my UINavigationController by reference to another class . but it is showing an error **Address of property expression requested**  .

MyUtil *util =[[MyUtil alloc] init];

[util NavAndBackBtn:&self.navigationController];// giving error here..

**MyUtil.m**

```
-(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UINavigationController **)nav // ** for passing by reference
{

 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,36,20);

UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[UIBarButton alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

//*nav.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbtn;// this gives error
//then i set this nav to Util nav

self.main_nav_ofUtilClass = *nav;

sefl.main_nav_ofUtilClass.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =barbtn;
}
```

**Problem**

how can i pass **UINavigationController by reference**.
so that whatever changing i did to UINavigationController in another class happens to it.

I simply want to add a back button image to UINavigationController in another class name MyUtil

Comment: If adding a button is the objective, why don't you try using a category? Keep a boolean to switch between default and custom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made mistake in method name

```
-(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UINavigationController **)nav
```

use insted of this

```
-(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UINavigationController *)nav
```

Remove `**`

Comment: it is not working bro. but i have changed by parameter to UINavigationItem it is working event is not handling see ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888037/handle-popviewcontrolleranimated-like-event-in-another-class