# Handle popViewControllerAnimated like event in another class?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have to create a same button in every ViewController. So i decided to write a class having this functionality once. I have created a class name **MyUtils** and added a back button to UINavigationItem and it displays correctly but don't know how to add an event to it in that class.

It displays accurately but no event is perform. I mean popViewControllerAnimated:YES

I call myUtil like

```
MyUtil *utils = [[MyUtil alloc] init];

[utils NavAndBackBtn:self.navigationItem];
```

**MyUtil.m**

```
-(void)NavAndBackBtn:(UINavigationItem *)nav 
{

 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(popView) forControlEventTouchUPInside];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,36,20);

UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[UIBarButton alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

nav.leftBarButtonItem = barbtn;// this gives error

}
-(void)popView
{
// [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //not working no method in self
}
```

But don't know how to add an event to `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` in MyUtil class. because i don't have the reference of self there.

**popView method**

there must be a way to get the context of the class . i mean self in this class. and add event on its behalf. And there is no method of UINavigationItem which will popViewController.

**In Simple Words**
I simply want to `popViewController` event on that button which i created in MyUtils . But it must be implemented in `MyUtils` class. How can i popViewControllerAnimated in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)showBackBarButton:(UIViewController*)controller{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [btn setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:controller.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,36,30)];
     UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barbtn;
}
```

On `ViewDiDLoad`

```
    [utils showBackBarButton:self];
```

Comment: now i have UINavigationItem not UINavigationController . It is a method of UINavigationController. whereas nav is a UINavigationItem here. Any other solution

Comment: By sending self.navigationController . I am unable to get nav.navigationItem.leftBarButton in that class. For that reason i have changed it to navigationItem. I also don't know while holding NavigationController why i can't get navigationItem in that class . I have already tried this solution . it even don't displays my buttton

Comment: Thanks a lot . now i understand how to send context because i have android background..

Comment: Main thing is what your target,,